# How to create composite key at ArrangoDB

Tags: c#, arangodb, composite-key

I used ArangoDB.Client in C#.
I am creating a resource class and making ResourceId and Locale as composite key.

```
public class Resource
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ResourceId {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Locale {get; set;}
    public string ResourceName {get; set;}
}
```

Above class doesn't work. I have to use as below and require to combine ResourceId and Locale to save as key.

```
public class Resource
{
    [DocumentProperty(Identifier = IdentifierType.Key)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Guid ResourceId {get; set;}
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Locale {get; set;}
    public string ResourceName {get; set;}
}
```

Please advice any other idea!

Comment: `ResourceId` type is `Guid` which is already unique itself, why you want to combine it with `Locale`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArangoDB key can only be set on one attribute named `_key`. with c# client you can only specify which one of class members should be translate to `_key` attribute.

I didn't do this myself but you can concat `ResourceId` and `Locale` and set it to `Key`(just be aware keys should be at most 254 bytes long)

```
public string Key => $"{ResourceId.ToString("N")}_{Locale}";
```

Or if you want these fields to be unique for each document, you can create a unique hash index on `ResourceId` and `Locale` and behave them as normal attributes.